# How to print huge matrix in less than 700ms?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I've managed to solve SPOJ problem. Its timelimit is 1s. But my algorithm runs in less than 400ms, but it takes about 2s to print the matrix. Is it possible to print this in less than 700ms?

```
char matrix[30000][30];
```

I tried to printf it with two for loops, then with printf as strings row by row, then I tried puts which also wasn't fast enought.
I also tried to print an array of 900000 chars with puts. It's currently the fastest way (1.6s).

The code below is the fastest I wrote with an array (30000*30 = 900000).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include<stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    char array[900000];

    for(int i = 0; i < 900000; i++)
        array[i] = '.';


    clock_t time_a = clock();
    puts(array);
    clock_t time_b = clock();
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Execution time of puts: " << (unsigned int)(time_b - time_a) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why is this tagged as C?

Comment: How long I/O takes depends heavily on the platform and type of stream. For example, writing to a console terminal is *much*  slower than writing to a file.

Comment: Totally depends on actual execution environment-

Comment: `array` is not null terminated. Crom only knows if and when it will stop printing.

Comment: Then how can I print huge output in 1s  based on input SPOJ gave in testing?

Comment: What spoj problem are you talking about? Send link.

Comment: @paulpaul1076 [SPOJ PROBLEM](http://www.spoj.com/problems/BGRAVITY/)

Comment: Have you tried building with the optimizer set to full? Next, drawing all this crap to the terminal is likely what's killing you. Try executing with the output piped (`program > out.txt`) to a file. Completion time should be less than you can measure.

Comment: @user4581301 Am I doing this right?
void printFile(){'

     ofstream out("out.txt");

     for (int i = 0; i < R - 1; i++)
      out << courtMatrix[i] << "\n";
     out << courtMatrix[R - 1];

     out.close();
    }

Comment: array[] should be null-terminated.

Comment: Looks good, but I recommend testing with `cout` and piping the output to a file rather than writing directly to a file. spoj will be expecting the result on stdout, and there's no sense testing one thing and submitting another.

Comment: @user4581301 Yep, not working. I've been googling like hell. So how can I fix this, based on function I sent you? :)
The thing you told me right now, I don't understand it :)

Comment: Not working in what way? Compiler, logic fault, SPOJ rejection, ...?

Comment: @user4581301 I only printed my output to file and nothing else. SPOJ said "wrong answer"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SPOJ is looking for the output on the console (`std::cout`). Unfortunately this makes testing real ugly because the output takes several seconds to print, skewing the program runtime toward the limitations of the graphics card and not the program itself, and the common console cannot hold the entire output making it hard to verify the output as correct.

Solution one: print the output to the console with std::cout, but have the operating system redirect (AKA pipe) the console output to a file. this is done with the following operator on both windows and most every *nix variant I've played with.

```
program.exe > outputfile.txt
```

the `>` operator signals the redirection.

Simple hack test code to demonstrate this follows:

```
#include <iostream> //cout
#include <chrono> // clock
#include <cstring> //memset

char courtMatrix[90000];

void printFile(char * matrix,
               size_t len)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len - 1; i++)
    {
        std::cout << matrix[i] << "\n";
    }
    std::cout << matrix[len - 1];
}

int main()
{
    // not using c-style standard IO, no sense paying for it.
    std::cout.sync_with_stdio(false);

    //initialize array contents
    memset(courtMatrix, '.', sizeof(courtMatrix));

    //start timer
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    //TODO generate output here
    //print output
    printFile(courtMatrix, sizeof(courtMatrix));
    // compute duration
    auto dur = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start);

    //output execution time. Note cerr, not cout. Different data stream and
    //won't pipe to file
    std::cerr << "Execution time : " << dur.count() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Executed as

```
test > test.txt
```

Typical output: one test.txt file and

> Execution time : 0

A quick note on `size_t`. `size_t` is an unsigned integer large enough to index the largest object representable on the system. That means it's big enough to handle any array you can build. It also eliminates the need to test for negative numbers and crap like that because a negative number will wrap to a huge positive and will be caught by an upper bounds check. Handy to use for indexes.

Back on topic, the above `printFile` function's output will be rejected by SPOJ because the output requirements seem to want the 2D matrix and deviating from this will probably result in a fail. In that case:

```
void printFile(char * matrix,
               size_t len,
               size_t rowlength)
{
    size_t rowleft = rowlength;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        std::cout << matrix[i] << ' ';
        rowleft--;
        // test if we've printed an entire row
        if (rowleft == 0)
        {
            // we have, so end the line and reset the counter
            rowleft = rowlength;
            std::cout << '\n';
        }
        /* could use the more elegant-looking

        if (i % rowlength) std::cout << '\n';

        but the % operator is often pretty expensive compared to --
        As always, test it and find out which suits your needs better.
        */
    }
}
```

Don't fear using a 2D array and nested for loops here. The improved readability will probably outweigh any performance hit once an optimizing compiler is done with it. A bit of profiling will tell you pretty quickly if I'm wrong.

Comment: I understood what you said with test > test.txt. so by executing this command all of my output will be written in text.txt. But how can I tell spoj to execute my program like that?

Comment: You don't. Odds are really good that your output is going somewhere much faster than an operator's display. Probably all console output goes directly to a buffer in RAM and is compared without a human eye or a file ever being generated.

Comment: I get now what are you saying. But still.
SPOJ is giving me TL for using cout<<, and W/A for printing the output to file.

Comment: You aren't getting the output that much faster. I recommend looking at the algorithm you use to generate the output for performance improvements. Perhaps rather than building and printing the output array, you can output the results as you generate them. I don''t know what development tools you use, but if they are GCC based, look into gprof. It will tell you where most of your time goes. For other tool chains I'm not as familiar, though I do like the profiler in Visual Studio 2015 Pro.

Answer (score 2):

Recapping, what already have been pointed out in the comments:

1. The variable `array` should be null terminated - you need `array[900000-1] = '\0';` after the initialization in the for loop or bad things could happen, because `std::put` does not know when to stop otherwise.
2. There is really a big difference whether you print to the console or to  a file (which is what the SPOJ-judge do):

Printing the output to the console (`./program`) takes 2 seconds on my machine, but only 0.001 seconds if the output is piped to a file (`./program > out.txt`).

Comment: When I print in file, should I do ` '\0' << out; ` ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to redirect your output to a file and somehow make SPOJ to check your answers in the output file.

However, there are a few optimizations that can be made to your come. For example, `cout` is not the fastest way to write something to the standard output.

Take a look at this post: [Yet again on C++ input/output](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/5217)

The author discusses and compares several I/O methods in C++ applied to competitive programming.